# How to extract inner text within nested parenthesis in a repeating manner using REGEX - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, nested

I have blown my brains out trying to figure out the solution to this issue.
I have to extract text between the nested parenthesis. The brackets can be nested or may be more than one inside. And the crazy part is that i want this to be done using REGEX in Javascript! Insane! I know!

Example:

```
(This    (is
     (a)
     (brain)    killer)  Aaah)  (I    (am)  pissed)  (REGEX  kills)
```

Output: `ThisisabrainkillerAaahIampissedREGEXkills`

I tried this:

```
(((?:<\w+>)*([\w\s]*)(?:<\/\w+>)*)\*)
```

to extract the words. But no luck!

Note: I just want them to be extracted into groups so that I can join them later on.

Comment: To get your output, you could just remove any `(` or `)`, right?

Comment: by brackets you mean `{` and `}` or parenthesis - `(` and `)` ?

Comment: @SebastianProske `(`, `)` and `[white space(s)]`.

Comment: @SebastianProske I could but i want them to be extracted into matching groups, so if i want to perform some validation or formatting, i could easily do that.

Comment: @Veverke you caught me, I'll correct it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split using this regex:

```js
var str = "(This (is (a) (brain) killer) Aaah) (I (am) pissed) (REGEX kills)";
var result = str.split(/\s*[()]\s*/);
// remove empty strings
result = result.filter(function(s) { return s.length; });
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need too much hassle with JS. Just use this one with a `String.prototype.match(/[^\(\)\s]+?(?=[\(\)\s])/g)` and you should be all fine.

```
[^\(\)\s]+?(?=[\(\)\s])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/40npLuOOVyLgILt_)

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zP4vY1/1)